# How to add Codeigniter Smileys in Bootstrap Popover Window?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to view codeigniter smileys in bootstrap popover window.but it doesn't work so please help me.

Bootstrap Popover is work good..Please See the Sample Picture->[View Image](http://jpcreation.site50.net/stackoverflow/work.PNG)

But Codeigniter Smileys are not show Properly..Sample Picture->[View Image](http://jpcreation.site50.net/stackoverflow/Capture.PNG)

**My Code is:**

```
<div class="panel-footer">
 <?php echo smiley_js(); ?>                                            
   <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><a id="example" href="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" title="Smileys" data-content='<?php echo $smiley_table;?>'><i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i></a></span>
        <input id="message" type="text" name="message" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm font1">
          <span class="fa fa-send"></span> Send Message </button>
        </span>
    </div>                                             
</div>
```

Advance Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add data attribute to allow showing html in popovers:

```
'data-html' => 'true'
```